# Information Management Policy and Records Declaration

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-on-prem

I Currently have a records declaration policy setup on a content type and it works as designed with one gotcha.

Here's the gotcha:
Item is declared as a record.
Super User undeclares the item, updates some metadata, then saves the changes.
The item is never re-declared as a record.

Policy info:
Non-records
  Event - Created Date + 1 year
Action - Declare record

1) Is this by design or do I need to update my retention policy?
2) Using PowerShell, is it possible to see if an item was ever declared as records?  List item property or some other field.

Answer (score 0):

It’s the default behavior that the retention policy works only once on the item.

You can check the Compliance details for the item to check if the item is ever declared as record.

Besides, you can use PowerShell command to re-declare these items as records.

Check the demo in the similar post: [Record declaration in document library](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/82279d91-399f-4ccb-b454-62ec9b4e190d/record-declaration-in-document-library?forum=sharepointadmin)

Comment: Any idea if the compliance details are available in the search properties of an item?  I'm working with a couple million documents and looping through them one at a time will be incredibly slow.